# Guest Student and Admin authentication

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I am trying to manage user roles with Laravel 4, but I can't clearly understand how it works, so I am gonna need some explanations.
This is what I want to do:

> If user is guest (not logged in), redirect to route `/`
>
> If logged user role is equal to `student`, redirect to `student/books`
>
> If logged user role is equal to `admin`, relocate to `admin/index`

What I want is to filter with slug and user role. The `user` table has the following columns:

```
first_name | email | password |role
```

How can I get to this, btw. I'm a newbee in Laravel so I will need a better explanation.

I assume the steps that I need are:

- To create a filter in `filters.php`
- To create route groups in `routes.php`

Comment: I would recommend using Zizaco's Entrust package for user roles and permissions: https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust It's one of the most used user/role packages, and learning it is easier than creating a system on your own.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have store user roles inside session `Auth::user()->role`

**filters.php**

```
Route::filter('isAdmin', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest() || Auth::user()->role !== "admin")
    {
        return Redirect::to('/');
    }
    elseif(Auth::user()->role == "admin"){

    }

});


Route::filter('isStudent', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest() || Auth::user()->role !== "student")
    {
        return Redirect::route('adm_index');
    }        }
    elseif(Auth::user()->role == "student"){
        return Redirect::route('std_books');
    }
});
```

**routes.php**

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'isStudent'), function()
{    
    Route::get('student/books',array('as'=>'std_books','uses'=>'BookController@method_name'));
});

Route::group(array('before' => 'isAdmin'), function()
{    
    Route::get('admin/index',array('as'=>'adm_index','uses'=>'AdminController@method_name'));  
});
```